# Are there more than two endings for Highrise Heroes?

Tags: highrise-heroes

I've reached the end of [Highrise Heroes](http://www.fallentreegames.com/games/highrise-heroes/), a word-building game kind of like [Bookworm](http://www.popcap.com/games/bookworm/online), but (usually) limited by turns rather than time, meaning you can be more deliberate.

The game sports a choice near the end, which result in a slightly different final level and a different cutscene at the end. I've gone through both of those. Now, while I've done my best, I haven't three-starred all of the levels and I haven't gained all of the achievements, things that sometimes unlock further endings.

Poking around on Google, I haven't found anyone mentioning more endings, but I figured I'd ask to see if anyone knew if there was any benefit other than bragging rights to get three-stars and achievements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Lewis, Art Director at Fallen Tree Games. We are the developer of Highrise Word Heroes.

There are two endings to the game. If you're still looking for things to do... have you completed all the challenges, found all the collectibles and unlocked all the achievements?